# OrderBy multiple custom meta fields

Tags: customization, order

I have a custom post type in my plugin named `members`, along with two custom fields; `first_name` and `last_name`. I am trying to order my listing my the last name, then the first name. The only solution I have found is one that utilizes a function to pull in the first two query meta fields and replaces them (I followed a tutorial at dotnordic.se). However, whenever I try this I have no posts returned. I have posted my code below. Any help on fixing the problem I have with my code or suggesting another way is greatly appreciated.

```
  // Shortcode Function
  function mba_members_list_code() {

  // WP_Query arguments
  $args = array (
  'post_type'       => 'member_data',
  'post_status'     => 'active',
  'fields'          => 'ids',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'meta_key'        => 'last_name',
  'orderby'         => 'meta_value',
  'order'           => 'ASC',
  'meta_query'      => array(
    array(
      'key'         => 'first_name',
    ),
    array(
      'key'         => 'last_name',
    ),
    array(
      'key'         => 'publicly_listed',
      'value'       => 'true',
    ),
  ),
);

// The Query
$posts = get_posts( $args );

// The Loop
if( $posts ) {
   echo "Total Members Found: " . count($posts) . "<br>";

   foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      $q = get_post_meta($post);
      echo "<b>" . $q['first_name'][0] . " " . $q['last_name'][0] . "</b><br>";
      echo $q['city'][0] . ", " . $q['state'][0] . " " . $q['zip'][0] . "<br>";
      echo "<a href='mailto:" . $q['email'][0] . "'>" . $q['email'][0] . "</a><br>";
      echo "<br>"; 
   }
   unset( $post );       
}else{
  echo "<b>Sorry, we found no active members. Please be sure to check back soon.</b>";
}
}
```

**EDIT**

```
function customorder($orderby) {
global $wpdb;
return ' {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value, mt1.meta_value';
//return str_replace('menu_order', 'mt1.meta_value, mt2.meta_value', $orderby);
}
```

I know that there are other questions on this with an answer to implement this same function; however, whenever I implement it, I have **no records/posts** returned.

Comment: Check this [link](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/). This feature is introduced in WP4.

Comment: @Nilambar I have read over this posting before. If I was only dealing with one custom value I believe this could work, but dealing with two custom values I have my doubts. I would have to have `Orderby meta_value ASC, meta_value ASC`, and then set two meta keys. Please correct me if I am wrong in my thinking.

Comment: What is `post_status=active`

Comment: This is a custom post status that is registered for my custom post type member_data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** (*Please see the original answer for full explanation of the code*)

The code in my original answer works as expected, but triggers a known bug with `usort` (Check the bug report here [#50688](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50688))

> WARNING Error: [2] usort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function

This bug is triggered only when the `fields` parameter is set in the arguments in `get_posts`, so the only workable workaround I could find was to remove the `fields` parameter and go with full posts being retrieved.

Here is the bug free working version

```
<?php
$args = array (
  'post_type'              => 'member_data',
  'post_status'            => 'active',
  'posts_per_page'         => -1,
  'meta_query'             => array(
    array(
      'key'       => 'first_name',
    ),
    array(
      'key'       => 'last_name',
    ),
    array(
      'key'       => 'publicly_listed',
      'value'     => 'true',
    ),
  ),
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

usort( $posts, function( $a, $b ){

    // sort first by last name
    $compare = strnatcmp(get_post_meta($a->ID, 'last_name', true), get_post_meta($b->ID, 'last_name', true));

    // if last names are identical, sort by first name
    if(!$compare) {
        return strnatcmp(get_post_meta($a->ID, 'first_name', true), get_post_meta($b->ID, 'first_name', true));
    }else{
        return $compare;
    }

});

if( $posts ) {
   echo "Total Members Found: " . count($posts) . "<br>";

   foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      $q = get_post_meta($post->ID);
      echo "<b>" . $q['first_name'][0] . " " . $q['last_name'][0] . "</b><br>";
      echo $q['city'][0] . ", " . $q['state'][0] . " " . $q['zip'][0] . "<br>";
      echo "<a href='mailto:" . $q['email'][0] . "'>" . $q['email'][0] . "</a><br>";
      echo "<br>"; 
   }
   unset( $post );       
}else{
  echo "<b>Sorry, we found no active members. Please be sure to check back soon.</b>";
}
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Unfortunately there is no way to do this type of sorting natively, so you will need to take a different approach here.

- Use `WP_Query`, or even better `get_posts` retrieve your posts as normal. There is no need to apply any sorting at this stage. In my personal opinion, this is useless as you can sort only by one `meta_value` and not two. I would rather just use php sorting to order the posts as needed. (If you are going to use pagination, rather use `WP_Query`).
- You are going to use `usort` to sort your posts, first by `last_name`, then if two or more persons share the same `last_name`, we will sort according to `first_name`.

### Here is the concept:

Before I start, I want to point out a few things

- Your `meta_query` is a mess unfortunately. Everything is within an array within an array within an array, where as it should be 3 separate arrays within one array
- I would rather use `get_posts` here and also only retrieve the post ID's as you aren't going to make use of any postdata or any of the other data returned by `WP_Query`
- This is quite a heavy operation as the db is visited two times for each post. You will have to look to make use of transients here.

**Now for the solution**

As said use `get_posts` to construct your query with. We are going to retrieve the posts which matches all three `meta_key`'s

```
$args = array (
  'post_type'              => 'member_data',
  'fields'                 => 'ids',
  'post_status'            => 'active',
  'posts_per_page'         => -1,
  'meta_query'             => array(
    array(
      'key'       => 'first_name',
    ),
    array(
      'key'       => 'last_name',
    ),
    array(
      'key'       => 'publicly_listed',
      'value'     => 'true',
    ),
  ),
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

We are now going to sort `$posts` by `last_name` then `first_name` using `usort`

```
usort( $posts, function( $a, $b ){

    // sort first by last name
    $compare = strnatcmp(get_post_meta($a, 'last_name', true), get_post_meta($b, 'last_name', true));

    // if last names are identical, sort by first name
    if(!$compare) {
        return strnatcmp(get_post_meta($a, 'first_name', true), get_post_meta($b, 'first_name', true));
    }else{
        return $compare;
    }

});
```

`$posts` should now be sorted alphabetically by `last_name`, and if the `last_name` is the same for two or more persons, they will be sorted in alphabetical order by `first_name`.

Your loop will now follow and look like this

```
if( $posts ) {
   echo "Total Members Found: " . count($posts) . "<br>";

   foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      $q = get_post_meta($post);
      echo "<b>" . $q['first_name'][0] . " " . $q['last_name'][0] . "</b><br>";
      echo $q['city'][0] . ", " . $q['state'][0] . " " . $q['zip'][0] . "<br>";
      echo "<a href='mailto:" . $q['email'][0] . "'>" . $q['email'][0] . "</a><br>";
      echo "<br>"; 
   }
   unset( $post );       
}else{
  echo "<b>Sorry, we found no active members. Please be sure to check back soon.</b>";
}
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working correctly. It sorting last name correctly, but when that last name is the same it just adds the newest record to the bottom the those names. You can actually see my demo at http://s2m.demo.accessdrive.net/test-shortcode/.

Comment: Are you using my code as-is. I've retested, and I can't seem replicate your problem. On my side everything works as expected. It does seem that you are making use of a shortcode, so if so, please edit your question and add your complete shortcode to your question.

Comment: I basically copied-and-pasted your code. I have updated the updated short code in my question.

Comment: Just one question, the page where you are using the shortcode, are there any custom queries on that page or any other shortcodes using a custom query. If so, all all of them resetted with `WP_reset_postdat();`

Comment: No, there are no other queries on this page.

Comment: Please see my updated code. This should do the trick

Comment: I updated my code with the new edits. Now none of the meta is displayed on the page. I edited at the bottom of the foreach with `var_dump(get_post_meta($post));` which yields `bool(false)` on all the posts.

Comment: Had a copy and paste error. Please see update

Comment: Thank you so much @Pieter for your help. Everything looks like it working.

Comment: Glad this worked out for you. Was fun working on this. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this from another post:

```
query_posts(
    array( 
        'post_type'      => 'custompost', 
        'posts_per_page' => 4, 
        'meta_key'       => 'mydate', 
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value', 
        'order'          => 'ASC', 
        'meta_query'     => array( 
            array( 
                'key'        => 'mydate', 
                'meta-value' => $value, 
                'value'      => $today, 
                'compare'    => '>=', 
                'type'       => 'CHAR' 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
);
```

Although you only need to sort by surname as the first name will be found in the loop in order of which you call it.

Comment: This would still only sort by one value, correct? I have tried this code before, but it still won't put the names in the correct/expected order.

Comment: Yes thats correct but surname and first name are linked to one person so unless do you mean sort either by surname or first ?

Comment: They are linked to one, but if I don't sort by both last name, the first name my results comes like: Charles Adams, Ashley Adams.